# Java desktop frameworks

Tags: java, frameworks, desktop-application

I am aware that there is a lot of framework for Java web apps, but I am surprised is there is any MVC framework for desktop apps in java other than Swing and AWT?

Comment: Just how many different frameworks do you want?  Personally, if one framework does the job, I feel that '1' is entirely sufficient.

Comment: true @Andrew Thompson I mostly prefer xml design fo view  and java as controller like zkoss for web framework  http://zkoss.org/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087013/java-gui-frameworks-which-are-out-there

Answer (score 2):

I can also recommend the NetBeans Platform, a RCP on top of Swing.

http://netbeans.org/features/platform/index.html

http://netbeans.org/features/platform/showcase.html

Answer (score 1):

SWT aka Eclipse RCP (http://www.eclipse.org/home/categories/rcp.php) is a good alternative to have a look at.